# Visual studio keeps jumping to current statement when debugging

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-debugging

When debugging, i stop at a break point and i scroll down a few dozen lines down. A couple of seconds later, it jumps back to the current statement.

For Example, i have a break point at line 10, then i scroll down to line 100. A couple seconds later, it jumps back to line 10.

I have tried going to Debug and looked at the options but nothing seems to describe my situation.

I dont know if this happens to other people...
FYI, im on Visual studio professional 2017, version 15.8.1

EDIT:
I left out an important info. This only happens when im working on a xamarin project. For my other projects, like an api solution, i have no issues.

Comment: You can report it to Visual Studio team in Visual Studio, select Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.

Comment: @Vibol, Does it have this issue in other VS machine? Did you get this issue before? Actually I also test it in my VS 2017 Pro 15.8.1 version, I didn't get this issue in my side. Whether all projects have the same issue in your side?

Comment: @Alex i will report this to VS team. Thanks.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT i actually noticed this only happens on my xamarin project. my other solutions are fine.

Comment: @Vibol, How can we create this xamarin project as yours? Is it the Android app(Xamarin) or other project type? Would you please share a simple sample or main code in your issue? So I could create a simple project and debug it in my side.

Comment: I have the same issue going on, also in Xamarin

Comment: @Martijn, It seems that other community members also got the same issue, would you please report it to the Product team directly? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio-2017?view=vs-2017

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT i upvoted another item with title Debugger won't let me leave execution point (Android) which seems to be the exact same problem

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed in Visual Studio 2017 version **15.8.5**: See [Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.8.5)

Here is the reported problem: [Debugger won't let me leave execution point](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/316908/debugger-wont-let-me-leave-execution-point-android.html)